# How to have a logging macro for __android_log_print with a different TAG on each .cpp file?

Tags: android, c++

Currently I have to insert all of this in every file I want to use the `ALOG` macros. Since each .cpp file would use a custom TAG, I cannot put this inside a .h file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define TAG "RecordingSwitcher.h"
#define ALOGV(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ALOGD(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ALOGI(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ALOGW(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ALOGE(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

I also cannot redefine the TAG after the .h file inclusion.

How can I stop copying and pasting these lines into every file but still use ALOG macros without code duplication?

Comment: What about a wrapper function you can call like `logger.warn(...)`?

Comment: @tadman but I'd have to redefine the function for each .cpp file?

Comment: It's unavoidable, really, if you want to include file contextual information. You can make it fairly easy with a macro, but the preprocessor has limits.